# Mat-chip-list call function when option added/changed

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I'm using a mat-chip-list and I have certain functionality that occurs when an option is removed. However, I'd also like something to happen when an option is added or in fact a call that happens when an option is added or removed (ie the contents change)

I've tried `(click)="testMethod()"`  and `(selectionChnaged)="testMethod()"`  but neither seems to work.

```
<mat-form-field class="btn-div" *ngIf="showSectors">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let sector of chosenSectors" [removable]="true" (removed)="removeSector(sector)">
            {{ sector.service_code + ": " + sector.service }}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
        <input placeholder="Sectors" #sectorInput [formControl]="sectorCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            [matChipInputFor]="chipList" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="true">
    </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let sector of filteredSectors | async" [value]="sector" matTooltip={{sector.commodity}}
            [matTooltipPosition]="'after'" [matTooltipShowDelay]="500">
            {{ sector.service_code + ": " + sector.service }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

The `(click)` functionality works when it is inside the mat-form-field but this isn't suitable as I will eventually be passing the value of the field through to the method I want to call and this value isn't set upon clicking of the mat-form-field.

Comment: can you try creating a demo on stackblitz to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: looking at https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples did you try `(matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"` on the `<input>`?